# Support for IPv6 support?

Tags: ipv6

This might sound very rudimentary to some but I am having trouble understanding the limitations of IPv6

My server has been assigned a block of IPv6 addresses by my hosting provider. According to my webhost, there is no need for IPv4 tunneling and ifconfig shows that eth0 has been successfully binded to an IPv6 address.

Assuming all my server software is properly configured, and my domain's AAAA record points to my IPv6 address, will all clients on all ISPs be able to open my domain? Or is IPv6 limited to only those ISPs/DNS servers that support the new protocol?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will all clients on all ISPs be able
>   to open my domain? Or is IPv6 limited
>   to only those ISPs/DNS servers that
>   support the new protocol?

The 2nd half is correct. Only ISPs that are offering IPv6, or users who are using IPv6 over a tunnel broker, will be able to connect to your websites IPv6 address.

Comment: +1. Basically ggo dual stack (Ipv4 and ipv6). They are two seaparate protocols. No interoprations out of the box (though there are proxy systems in development).